# Actualizar gridview con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp

Esty tratando de actualizar un gridview con un datasource y un procedimiento almacenado que tengo en sql server pero me arroja el siguiete error: Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
Procedure or function SP_ACTUALIZARAREA has too many arguments specified.

Viendo los parametros que tengo en el procedimiento que actualiza, coincide con los parametros de envio, sera que me falta algo?

este el codigo del datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 

    ConnectionStrings:BibliotecaConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SP_LISTAREA" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="SP_ACTUALIZARAREA" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ARECOD" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ARENOMBRE" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ARETIEMPO" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

y este es el proc que tengo en sqlserver:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SP_ACTUALIZARAREA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC SP_ACTUALIZARAREA

GO

CREATE PROC SP_ACTUALIZARAREA(@ARECOD INT,@ARENOMBRE NVARCHAR(50),@ARETIEMPO INT)
AS
 UPDATE dbo.Area SET areCodigo=@ARECOD,areNombre=@ARENOMBRE,areTiempo=@ARETIEMPO WHERE areCodigo=@ARECOD
```

Agreadezco la ayuda si hay algo que no he podido ver para solucionarlo.

Comment: se que suena un poco obvio, pero ¿estas mirando la misma BD? podrá ser que estas trabajando en test y productivo??... por lo demás se ve bien la cantidad y nombre de los parámetros.